# Leer configuración desde afuera de Startup.cs en .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Necesito definir una parametro en el archivo `appsettings.json` y poder leerlo desde una clase en particular.

Actualmente solo puede verla en el archivo `Startup.cs` pero no sé como leerlo desde otra clase.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string foo = Configuration["Foo"];
    }
}
```

La clase donde quiero usar la configuración es del siguiente estilo.

```
public class UsarFoo
{
    public static usarFoo()
    {
        // Aquí quiero usar el parámetro foo
    }
}
```

Comment: puedes definir un metodo estatico para la obtencion de tu parametro en la clase starup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La recomendación, es que puedas injectar en tu clase el **[IConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.2)**. 
Esto lo puedes hacer desde cualquier clase que necesites (ejemplo es cuando lo hacemos en Controladores por ejemplo de MVC o WebAPI), y que tenga el componente nuget [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/) ya que se encuentra en el assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll asi lo puedes llamar desde cualquier clase en cualquier componente. 
Pero debes injectar para utilizar IConfiguration (pero si no lo tienes con DI en todo tu aplicacion, queno lo mencionas, te lo recomiendo)

Puedes armar tu propia clase de configuracion, incluso estática ([static de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) y mapear key por key los valores que necesites

- Algo asi: **Configuration[path:key]** deberia ser **Configuration["Template:Title"]**

O puedes utilizar el metodo Bind (que esta en otro componente nuget [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/) que mapea directamente un objeto/clase (sin tener que hacer de uno a uno las propiedades, similiar a AutoMap)

Veamos un ejemplo sencillo. Donde tenemos una clase CurrentConfiguration en un assembly por separado del proyecto (libreria) para poder compartirlo. Como es estatico, en mi caso llamo especificamente al metodo Build para que se vaya "armando", y en cada Build de cada base tiene la llamada a

```
this.Propiedad1 = configuration["Elemento1:Propiedad1"]
```

Algo asi

```
public class CurrentConfiguration : ICurrentConfiguration
{
  public ILayoutConfig Layout { get; set; }
  public ITemplateConfig Template { get; set; }
  public ISmtpConfig Smtp { get; set; }

  public static ICurrentConfiguration Build(IConfiguration configuration,
                                            IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    var current = new CurrentConfiguration()
    {
        Layout = LayoutConfig.Build(configuration),
        Template = TemplateConfig.Build(configuration),
        Smtp = SmtpConfig.Build(configuration)
    };

    return current;
}
```

}

Donde en cada Build interno, arma y lee la configuración necesaria
Y para armar todo... en el Startup deberias tener algo asi

```
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        CurrentEnvironment = env;

        Configuration = configuration;

        CurrentConfiguration =
            App1.Componente.Core.Configuracion.CurrentConfiguration.Build(configuration, env);
```

Ademas hay un componente que no utilice que es **IOptions**, asi que le puedes dar una mirada [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2), donde tiene elementos interesantes que nos pueden ayudar (todavia no lo probé) pero tiene

- Notificacion de cambio (util...)
- Re-Lectura(tambien util)
  Te dejo como inquietud sobre todo

Enlaces que te pueden sirvir de ayuda o guia

- [IConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfiguration?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- Componente Nuget [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/)
- [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir una clase con el valor de tus parametros:

```
public class Parametros
{
    public string NombreBaseDeDatos{ get; set; }
}
```

En tu clase startup definir un metodo estatico que devuelve esa clase parametros:

Cuando inicias tu clase

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

        _parametros.NombreBaseDeDatos = Configuration["BaseDeDatos"];
    }

    private static Parametros _parametros { get; set; }

    static public Parametros ObtenerParametros()
    {
        return _parametros;
    }
}
```

Para llamarla solo:

```
var nombreDB=startup.ObtenerParametros().NombreBaseDeTatos;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta para entender como funciona y econtrar una forma más sencilla de lograr el mismo resultado que dejaré como respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Para leer la configuración es necesario dejar el atributo `configuration` como estatico y el `set`, como se ve acontinuación:

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
```

Para utilizarlo desde una clase externa se debe llamar de la siguiente forma:

```
public class UsarFoo
{
    public static usarFoo()
    {
        Startup.Configuration["Foo"];
    }
}
```